# Can a movie name include emoji or can it be entirely written using emojis?

Tags: title

Is there some kind of regulation when it comes to movie names?

I *clearly* see the downsides of including in the movie title emojis or any 
o̹̥̱̪̹t͔͕̞h̖̻̞è̳̩̗͎r̼̣̹͔̞ ҉͇̟̲͍̟̠s̮̖͓̣͔͈̺t͏͈̩̰͍r͔̣͈̘̙͍ͅa̧͇n̤̳̬̹̖͓g̷͈͇͇̦̗̮e͔̻͕̠ ̗̫̱͉̫a̛̝͖̫̞nd̳̟̠̙̩̱͕ ͍̗̝̳͜u̢n̮̰co̬͕̠̝̣m̻̼̦͞m̡̭͉̙̝̟̹͈o̙n̠̩͈͖̥ ҉̣̜͔c̫̜̠̮̳h̬͇̮̱a̸̻̝̙̲̙͈̖ṟa͏͙̩̯̲̮͎̥c̼̣̦̮̣̲͟te̗̦ŗ̜s̰͖̹̙̖, but are there any rules?

Comment: One would imagine that in these days of IMDB & internet searches it would be counter-productive to use unsearchable characters, so I doubt it needs a rule. It's hard enough trying to get results searching for "Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D." because of all the punctuation.

Comment: @Tetsujin There's a tendency to spell the movie title _Se7en_ wrong too, which messes with search results.

Comment: “I ♥ Huckabees” comes to mind.

Comment: I think in the end this is inherently a business and legal question related to trademark and copyright and text searches, etc. Of course a studio or producer can artistically do whatever they want, so the real thrust of the question is what are the legal and financial consequences of a title that can’t be written with language centered Unicode characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly the spec script for the movie "The Package" was called, ["Eggplant Emoji"](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/netflix-wins-bidding-war-eggplant-emoji-ben-stiller-workaholics-creators-968990) when Netflix had purchased it, it was renamed to 'the package' and Netflix continues to advertise it solely as the eggplant emoji.

[image: The package]

However, of course once mousing over, it gives its actual title, so likely this is just a kind of easter egg. But with that said, I remember it vividly as the only movie I've ever seen that didn't have a title with it, besides the eggplant emoji.

As far as specific regulations go, no amount of googling has let me find a naming regulation, advised or forced otherwise that explicitly prohibits naming of films in any sort of meaningful way, besides changing its potential rating. (Namely going from say, PG, R, X, or XXX).

As such, It appears that no, there are no limits on using odd symbols or emojis. Besides the fact a person would probably forget the title of the film, or hard to find.

Some Regulations:

[britishfilm commission](http://britishfilmcommission.org.uk/guidance/regulations/)

[CFC Film regulations](http://economy.scag.ca.gov/Economy%20site%20document%20library/CFC_Film_Regulations_Policies.pdf)

[Motion Picture Act Regulations](http://www.bclaws.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/260_86)

Comment: Remember when Prince changed his name to 'squiggle' & everybody had to refer to him as "The artist formerly known as Prince"?

Comment: yes, however I'm not sure about the connection...Prince was a musician and not a movie title. If you're referring to my comment on "..probably forget..."...symbols have different meanings depending on cultural and social circles. Had I not mentioned the title of the movie "the package" it could easily be thought of as...anything penis related or just plants or ???. Things would quickly get out of control, become unmemorable and annoying if symbols were rampant . I don't look forward to a day to discuss a movie starting with "remember ʕ·͡ᴥ·ʔ?"

Comment: Prince's 'squiggle' wasn't from any alphabet, it was a completely invented logo/icon & therefore couldn't be written at all. It was just the ultimate in unsearchable 'names'.

Comment: That is true...though, i didnt do much googling in the early 90s.

Comment: Yeah, it was Alta Vista back then ;) but for sure, it was far less of a concern.

Answer (score 0):

How about [*$*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollars_(film))?

> [image]

Considering it was released in 1971, it doesn't technically use an emoji. But the right emoji exists: .

---

For more see [TV Tropes: Lucky Charms Title](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LuckyCharmsTitle).